# How to run the powershell script simultaneously on multiple computers

Tags: windows, powershell, parallel-processing

I am trying to run the PowerShell script, which I have, on multiple computers simultaneously. Currently, I'm using PowerShell version 5.

I want to know is it possible to run it without background process, to check for the better understanding of logs.

```
$computers = @("Hostname1", "Hostname2", "Hostname3")
$scriptPath = "C:\Projects\Scripts\Environment\InstallEnvironment.ps1"

$scriptBlock = {
    param (
        [string]$scriptPath
    )
    try {
        # Execute the script
        & $scriptPath
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Error occurred on $($env:COMPUTERNAME): $_"
    }
}
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $scriptPath -Name $computer
}
while (Get-Job -State Running) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
Get-Job | Receive-Job
Get-Job | Remove-Job
```

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have three options:

- Continue with Jobs, but refactor your code a bit
- Use `ForEach-Object -Parallel` in PowerShell 7
- Try to use [Workflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1) in PowerShell 5, that allow `foreach -Parallel ($a in $x) {}` which are a different kind of headache

Here's a code snippet that uses `Invoke-Command` to create the jobs, and `Wait-Job` to wait for them:

```
$computers = @("Hostname1", "Hostname2", "Hostname3")
$scriptPath = "C:\Projects\Scripts\Environment\InstallEnvironment.ps1"
$scriptBlock = {
    try {
        & $Using:scriptPath
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Error occurred on $($env:COMPUTERNAME): $_"
    }
}
$Jobs = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ComputerName $computers -AsJob
# Results (Logs) are stored in the $Result variable
$Result = $Jobs | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
$Jobs | Remove-Job
```

Here's how you could use `ForEach-Object -Parallel`, but be warned, sometimes this does not let you output stuff to the console like you normally would, and can give you other sorts of headaches:

```
#Requires -Version 7
$computers = @("Hostname1", "Hostname2", "Hostname3")
$scriptPath = "C:\Projects\Scripts\Environment\InstallEnvironment.ps1"
$scriptBlock = {
    try {
        & $Using:scriptPath
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Error occurred on $($env:COMPUTERNAME): $_"
    }
}
$computers | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ComputerName $_
}
```

I'd absolutely recommend to stay with Jobs and get your logs via `Receive-Job`

Comment: -Yes, how would I view the logs if I keep the Receive-Job